# Finding the limit $\frac {\sin x - \arctan x}{x^2 \ln x}$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ in Petrovic

Tags: calculus, limits

Finding the limit:
 $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac {\sin x - \arctan x}{x^2 \ln x}$$

**My questions:**

1- I think the question should be corrected to as $x \rightarrow 0^+$, because of the domain of $\ln x$ ...... am I correct?

2- I applied L`hopital 2 times and after the second time it gaves me $0/-\infty $ which is $0$ .... am I correct?

Comment: Your observations are both correct.

Comment: Yes to both.  There are other methods too, such as power series, to show the limit is  0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the domain of $\ln{x}$ the limit should approach as $x \rightarrow 0^{+} $

Solving the limit, on seeing the numerator the first thought is expansion but $\ln{x}$ does not have an easy expansion, so go for double L'hôspital. This gives

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{-\sin{x} + \frac{2x}{{1+x}^{2}}}{2\ln{x}+3} =0$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

$$\dfrac{\sin x-\arctan x}{x^2\ln x}=\left(\underbrace{\dfrac{\sin x-x}{x^3}}-\underbrace{\dfrac{\arctan x-x}{x^3}}\right)\dfrac x{\ln x}$$

Using [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion), the terms with underbrace have finite limits.

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\dfrac x{\ln x}=\dfrac0{-\infty}=0$$